# MC - Dataview - activity ID = activity name mapping

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-views, custom-activity, activity

I want to know message results per journey. I'm using a 3rd party app for messaging, and the results are only shown as activity ID not activity name, so I can't define which message result this is.

**For example, if i send 3 different messages, in 1 journey,
I change the name of message activity into

a. message 1 (activity name) - 23fjydkjb (activity ID - randomly generated by MC)

b. message 2 (activity name) - 45djfkasj (activity ID - randomly generated by MC)

c. message 3 (activity name) - 76dfasfbf (activity ID - randomly generated by MC)

I can only see the activity ID (23fjydkjb) so it is hard to define which message this is.

To map activity ID and activity name, I found out that I might need to use DataView. (using automation studio - query)

Can you please let me know which query I should use?

ex.
SELECT ActivityID

FROM   [_VersionID]

WHERE ActivityName ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the activity IDs you got are journey activity IDs. You would want to use `_JourneyActivity` and `_Journey` data views to link with the journey you want to find out and then get the Activity name.

Check this [Data Views diagram](https://sfmarketingcloudhome.files.wordpress.com/2022/10/dataviews_2022_v3.jpg) from [zuzannamj](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50456/zuzannamj) to understand how they link with each other.

I would try something like this:

```SQL
SELECT
a.ActivityID,
a.ActivityName,
a.ActivityType
FROM
_JourneyActivity as a
INNER JOIN
_Journey as b
ON a.VersionID = b.VersionID
WHERE
b.JourneyName = 'YOUR JOURNEY NAME'
AND
b.VersionNumber = 'YOUR JOURNEY VERSION NUMBER'
AND
a.ActivityType = 'EMAILV2'
```

In this sample query, I get all activity IDs and their activity names by Email type. If you would like to have a generic version, then you can remove the last condition of the query.